# How do I change the image of a UIbutton if selected?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a button called

```
 @IBAction func likeIt(_ sender: Any) {
    }
```

and I have two images called

like and likeSelected

how do I change the button picture when pressed and when not pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to give the button an initial image in the storyboard by setting the Image property.

[image]

Then after that you can set the button's image on highlighted state like below.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonView: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        buttonView.setImage(UIImage(named: "likeSelected"), for: .highlighted)
    }

}
```

Comment: what if that button is in a UIcollection view? will this still work? it says Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'setImage'

Comment: @Nael yes it will still work just that the implementation for collection view and table view will be slightly different. Perhaps you can raise another question (be sure to include your source code) and I will be able to help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to check out Apple's documentation!

You're looking for [UIButton.setImage(_:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage).  For states, see [UIControl.State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/state).